# Necessary and Sufficient Condition for cyclic $H$ to be a homomorphic image of cyclic $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ and $H$ be cyclic groups. I need to find and prove a necessary and sufficient condition in order for $H$ to be homomorphic to $G$.

By the [Fundamental Theorem on Homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms), the possible homomorphic images of $G$ are isomorphic to $G/N$, where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

So, is a necessary and sufficient condition for $H$ to be the homomorphic image of $G$ that $H \simeq G/N$?

I was also told to use the following theorem to describe such a necessary and sufficient condition:

> **Theorem on the Classification of Cyclic Groups**:
>
> 1. An infinite cyclic group is isomorophic to $\mathbb{Z}$.
> 2. A finite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ for some $n \geq 1$.
> 3. Groups $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ are not isomorphic for distinct $m$ and $n$.

How does this fit together with my necessary and sufficient condition (assuming it's correct)?

If my necessary and sufficient condition is not correct, what is a correct condition? And how would one go about proving such a condition?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a guess as to the answer?

Comment: Where must a generator of $G$ be mapped to in $H?$

Comment: @ChrisLeary, not entirely sure where this is coming from, but I'm going to say $e_{H}$.

Comment: @Jessy Cat - The group $H$ must be the image of a homomorphism mapping $G$ onto $H$. This can happen only if a generator of $H$ is in the image of the map. What the map does is determined by what it does to a generator of $G.$

Comment: @ChrisLeary so is that the necessary and sufficient condition I seek and that I need to prove here?

Comment: Do you mean to find necc. and suff. condition for map $\varphi:G \to H$ to be homomorphism?

Comment: @SantoshLinkha that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Apparently you always seem to have [a map](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mapping_to_Identity_is_Unique_Constant_Homomorphism) which is homomorphism. I mean you can always construct some homomorphic map.

Comment: Does existence of such (any) map prove what you want to prove?

Comment: @SantoshLinkha I don't think that's helpful.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood your question. It was to show that $\varphi:G \to H$ is epimorphism rather than just homomorphism.

Comment: And probably if you show there exists a such map (which you can pick any one), then we are done. You also get nece. and suff. condition from here.

Comment: @Jessy Cat - see arctic tern's comment following Berci's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is correct (and even more general): $H$ is a homomorphic image of $G$ iff *there is an* $N\trianglelefteq G$ such that $H\cong G/N$.

However, using that a cyclic group is determined by its cardinality, we can give a straighter answer:

1. Each cyclic group is a homomorphic image of $\Bbb Z$, the infinite cyclic group.
2. If $n|m$, we have a surjective homomorphism $\Bbb Z_m\to\Bbb Z_n$.
3. If $\Bbb Z_n\cong\Bbb Z_m/N$ for any (normal) subgroup $N$ of $\Bbb Z_m$, we have $n|m$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47308/discussion-on-answer-by-berci-necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-cyclic-h).