# Let $G$ and $H$ be cyclic groups. Find a necessary and sufficient condition when $H$ is a homomorphic image of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I think the condition is that $H$ is a homomorphic image of $G$ iff *there is an* $N\trianglelefteq G$ such that $H\cong G/N$, but I don't know how to prove it.

I saw this question posted elsewhere here, but the answer wasn't complete/they finished explaining in chat so I'm a little lost.  Here is the original question for reference:

[Necessary and Sufficient Condition for cyclic $H$ to be a homomorphic image of cyclic $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972098/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-cyclic-h-to-be-a-homomorphic-image-of-c)

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably lacking is just some comfort with the isomorphism theorems.  You need to know that if $G$ is a group and we have a homomorphism $f:G \to G'$ then $ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and that $G/ker(f) \cong Im(f)$

So if we have $f: G \to H$ where $f(G) = H$, then the isomorphism theorem tells us that $G/ker(f) \cong H$ and so there exists a normal subgroup $N = ker(f)$ such that $G/N \cong H$.

Answer (score 1):

For $H$ to be a homomorphic image of $G$, there must be a surjective map $G \to H$. Since $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ and $H \cong \mathbb{Z}/ m \mathbb{Z}$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, such a map exists only when $m$ divides $n$.

If $G$ is infinite, then $H$ is always the homomorphic image of $G$, since it's a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$. If $H$ is infinite then $G$ must also be infinite.

Comment: Not to be annoying as this is, ofcourse, true ; however nothing says that $G$ is finite here.

Comment: @Dionel of course if $G$ is infinite then it is a free group and every cyclic group is a homomorphic image of it,

Comment: @DionelJaime Edited